# how to time a thing at 11:59 PM

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Discordpy with cogs:

How I could time an action to write it every day at 11:59 PM, but I want that I can restart the bot, so how I can save the time or request the time and check if it is 11:59 PM?

Thanks

I want to do a daily reward in my bot, but if I know to time it, I can implement it easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply create a [Task](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=task) that runs every X time and checks for the current time using `datetime` module before doing something.

```py
from datetime import datetime

@tasks.loop(minutes=1.0)
async def task(self):
    if datetime.now().hour == 23 and datetime.now().minute == 59:
        # Do something
```